# How can I run Ubuntu Server in verbose mode?

Tags: boot, server, grub2, ssh

I have ubuntu server running on a machine in a cupboard and would like to attach a monitor to see error messages without needing to ssh into the machine all the time.

Would this be possible to do?

I changed the parameter `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in grub to `text` which looked like it was working but I realise it only outputs the boot in verbose, before opening a blank terminal session.

Comment: You should not need to change any parameters. STDERR should print to the attached monitor automatically.

Comment: Just turn off graphical boot and quiet on the grub command line.